# Php form processing script not submitting to db or displaying any errors why

Tags: php, mysql, post, mysqli

I am using the following script to process a php form on my website, when I hit submit on the form the script below is then supposed to save the data to the db. The problem I am having is that its not saving any of the data to the mysql database, but its also not throwing any errors on why its not either ! ?.

```
    <link href='template/css/admin.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <?php
    if (isset($_POST['customerID'])) {$customerID = $_POST['customerID'];}else {$customerID = '';}
    if (isset($_POST['datecreated'])) {$datecreated = $_POST['datecreated'];}else {$datecreated = '';}
    if (isset($_POST['name'])) {$name = $_POST['name'];}else {$name = '';}
    if (isset($_POST['facebookuserurl'])) {$facebookuserurl = $_POST['facebookuserurl'];}else {$facebookuserurl = '';}
    if (isset($_POST['tel'])) {$tel = $_POST['tel'];}else {$tel = '';}
    if (isset($_POST['email'])) {$email = $_POST['email'];}else {$email = '';}
    if (isset($_POST['address'])) {$address = $_POST['address'];}else {$address = '';}
    if (isset($_POST['itemforrepair'])) {$itemforrepair = $_POST['itemforrepair'];}else {$itemforrepair = '';}
    if (isset($_POST['repairdetails'])) {$repairdetails = $_POST['repairdetails'];}else {$repairdetails = '';}
    if (isset($_POST['otherdetails'])) {$otherdetails = $_POST['otherdetails'];}else {$otherdetails = '';}
    if (isset($_POST['itemnumber'])) {$itemnumber = $_POST['itemnumber'];}else {$itemnumber = '';}
    if (isset($_POST['pricequoted'])) {$pricequoted = $_POST['pricequoted'];}else {$pricequoted = '';}
    if (isset($_POST['partprice'])) {$partprice = $_POST['partprice'];}else {$partprice = '';}
    $profit = $pricequoted - $partprice;
    if (isset($_POST['datepartordered'])) {$datepartorderedpre = $_POST['datepartordered'];$date = DateTime::createFromFormat("D F d, Y", $datepartorderedpre);$datepartordered = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($datepartorderedpre));}else {$datepartorderedpre = ''; $datepartordered = '';}
    if (isset($_POST['jobstatus'])) {$jobstatus = $_POST['jobstatus'];}else {$jobstatus = '';}
    if (isset($_POST['dateofcompletion'])) {$dateofcompletionpre = $_POST['dateofcompletion'];$date = DateTime::createFromFormat("D F d, Y", $dateofcompletionpre);$dateofcompletion = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($dateofcompletionpre));}else {$dateofcompletionpre = ''; $dateofcompletion = '';}



    // Checks to see if the key value is set
    if (isset($_GET['key'])) {$key = $_GET['key'];} else {$key = '';}

    // Checks to see if the key value is valid to authenticate the user
    if ($key == 'mysecretkey'){
    // If the key value is correct the user is granted access

    include("connectmysqli.php"); 

    $stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE `jobdetails` SET  itemnumber='$itemnumber',datecreated='$datecreated',customerID='$customerID',name='$name',facebookuserurl='$facebookuserurl',tel='$tel',email='$email',address='$address',itemforrepair='$itemforrepair',repairdetails='$repairdetails',otherdetails='$otherdetails',pricequoted='$pricequoted',partprice='$partprice',profit='$profit',datepartordered='$datepartordered',jobstatus='$jobstatus',dateofcompletion='$dateofcompletion' WHERE customerID='$customerID'");
    $stmt->execute(); 
    if (!$stmt)
        echo $db->error . "\n";
    $stmt->close();


    header('Location: jobsmanager.php?&key='.$key);
    }
    else {
    // Denies the user access if the key value isnt correct 
    echo '<h1>Access Denied !</h1>';}
    ?>
```

Comment: check the query with the help of echo

Comment: How do I echo the query ?

Comment: add `echo "UPDATE `jobdetails` SET  itemnumber='$itemnumber',datecreated='$datecreated',customerID='$customerID',name='$name',facebookuserurl='$facebookuserurl',tel='$tel',email='$email',address='$address',itemforrepair='$itemforrepair',repairdetails='$repairdetails',otherdetails='$otherdetails',pricequoted='$pricequoted',partprice='$partprice',profit='$profit',datepartordered='$datepartordered',jobstatus='$jobstatus',dateofcompletion='$dateofcompletion' WHERE customerID='$customerID'"`  `die();`

Comment: Debug your code and check on which line it is break and is it going in if statement or not.

Comment: Just curious, why PHP users are *so* eager to write WALLS of code?

Comment: That doesnt do anything ?

Comment: Did you receive the needed data in the script ? do a `die(var_dump($_POST))` at the begining to check it.

Comment: Yes I have already echo'd all the post data and it come up fine.

Comment: Even if I strip out all but one of the posted data fields at the top it still fails, so im not sure if something is going wrong with the DB part of it ?.

Answer (score 1):

you are checking for errors wrong way.

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("...");
if (!$stmt) trigger_error($db->error); // you need th check it right after prepare
$stmt->execute();
```

you also need to make sure you can see PHP errors, at least this way

```
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

And of course your query is vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: After adding the php errors I get the following error :
Fatal error: Call to undefined method DateTime::createFromFormat() in /home3/websit52/public_html/mobileithelp/editsubmitjob.php on line 18

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have worked this out now, the DateTime::createFromFormat() wasnt supported by the PHP 5.2 on my hosting account, so after some fiddling in the control panel I have upgraded it and it appears to be working now as expected.